# Is there a Mac equivalent of DOSBox?

Tags: powerpc, classic-mac-os

I was trying to run some old software on my Air today and I got these messages:

> You can't open the application because the classic environment is no longer supported.

> You can't open the application because PowerPC applications are no longer supported.

Is there an emulator or other piece of software that allows me to run this? Windows has DOSBox. Is there a similar program for macOS?

Comment: You can use a VM to run an older version of MacOS which does support PowerPC apps.

Comment: @NoahL would I have to buy an older version of MacOS to install in the VM or is there a free solution?

Comment: I have a Snow Leopard install DVD and VMWare Fusion (and the next-to-last version of Fusion if need be). If there is any particular software you would like me to try before you spend time and money, please feel free to ask

Comment: Make sure it's the server version of Snow Leopard; the client version is not licensed for VM use and Fusion will not allow it to install.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to run classic Mac OS 9 applications on modern computers is to run the SheepShaver Emulator. I'm assuming that since your mac says the Classic Environment is no longer supported, you are trying to run a Mac OS 9 or below app.

http://www.emaculation.com/doku.php/sheepshaver_mac_os_x_setup

ROM files and classic disc images are easy enough to find online, but I won't link you any just in case it is against copyright regulations.